# How to inherit and replace a @Entity from commons package?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have an `@Entity` in a commons package:

```
@Entity("person")
public class Person {
    //fields...
}
```

In an implementing application, I want to extend this entity with some custom fields.
But I still want to map to table `person`:

```
@Entity("person")
public class Person extends org.commons.Person {
    //additional fields
}
```

Result:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException: The [Person] and [CustomPerson] entities 
share the same JPA entity name: [person] which is not allowed
```

So how can I extend that entity and tell spring to somehow "forget" about the parent Person entity, so that only my `CustomPerson` is loaded?

Comment: Just use a different entity name. Why would you name it the same as the parent class anyway?

Comment: Not an answer, but: I would violate the _DRY_ principle here and just copy the class from commons. The simple reason is that if the entity in `commons` should change, which might not be under your control, your custom person entity could break. That might be as simple as renaming a field in a `@Column`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are assigning the same name to both entities. [You don't need to do that](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-the-single_table-inheritance-with-jpa-and-hibernate/). You can annotate your parent entity with @Entity, @Table and @Inheritance (which by default employs single table inheritance) and your subclass entities with just @Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table("person")
@Inheritance
public class Person {
    //fields...
}
@Entity
public class CustomPerson extends Person {
    //additional fields
}
```

Comment: I thought the target table name would be derived from the `@Entity` annotation and would thus require to be the same name.

Comment: I came back to this today, and discovered that `@Inheritance` is not even required to inherit the table name.